# How long can Photo Booth record video?

Tags: macos, applications, snow-leopard, software, photo-booth

Does anyone know how long Photo Booth can record video with iSight camera on Mac? I want to record for a few days non stop, and don't know if that's possible even if there is sufficient space in HD? I'm using OS X 10.6.

Answer (score 2):

### Your HD storage space is the limiting factor

There is no reasonable limit to the file size of Photo Booth video's. Photo Booth stores video's with `AAC` audio and `H.264` video compression.

Video will take the most storage space. The [H.264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) uses a lossy video compression method. The amount of compression is usually defined by the amount of motion in your video. A tripod mounted camera recording of a vase with flowers will result in a smaller file size than a hand filmed recording of a flock of birds.

So your answer in short, your HD storage space is the limiting factor. Record for one hour and see how much space you needed for your type of video.

---

If you are only interested in 'changes in your scene', try another option, like [senstic](http://www.senstic.com/mac/MotionDetector/MotionDetector.aspx) (the first google hit, nothing special)

Comment: I have no clue how Photo Booth will quit when the disks gets full. If it crashes, you might have lost your video! You should experiment with this before you 'go for real'.